# Metadata rejected but need to change binary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app was rejected for not providing valid test account credentials, however the reason these credentials dont work is a problem with the binary.

I resubmitted with what I believed was an updated binary and was rejected again but the problem I think is that the original binary is being used for review.

What is the correct process to update this binary? I incremented the build number and archived / uploaded.

Is there anyway to restart the submission process to be sure, the current status of the app in itunesconnect is iOS 1.0 Metadata Rejected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the binary to `Developer Rejected`

Make sure that you update the version number as well, even if you haven't really changed anything

Comment: I cant believe it, I didnt see the build section. I was submitting an old build. I have removed it and add a new build with incremented version to be sure. Thanks